# No data context found for binding XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can someone please tell me why binding doesnt work here, im trying to bind this string CountDisplay to label text but it says that No data context i found this is xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PapucoMetar.Views.Skener"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto,Auto,*">
        <Label
                Grid.Row="1"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                Text="{Binding CountDisplay}"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="ButtonCount"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Click me"
            Clicked="ButtonClicked_Clicked"
            />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and these is code behind:

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace PapucoMetar.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Skener : ContentPage
    {
        public Skener()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
        int count = 0;
        string countDisplay = "Click me";
        public string CountDisplay
        {
            get => countDisplay;
            set
            {
                if (value == countDisplay)
                    return;
                countDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private void ButtonClicked_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            CountDisplay = $"You clicked button {count} time(s)";
        }

    }
}`
```

I tried to bind number of click on button but for some reason it doesnt recognise string CountDisplay.

Comment: either disable XamlCompilation OR add a `DataType` property in your XAML.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings

Comment: Im sorry but where would I put DataContext here?

Comment: in the `<ContentPage>`

Comment: Well disabling XamlCompilation didnt work and I cant add datatype bc i dont have ViewModel

Comment: *”disabling XamlCompilation didn’t work”*: even though intellisense complains, if you build and run without XamlCompilation, it should work. HOWEVER, there is likely a XamlCompilation set elsewhere, globally. To be sure it is disabled, you could do `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]`. Jason’s answer is better; I am just explaining compilation options.

Comment: Thats what I did but it didnt work

Comment: @St3fKe This is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/0jVRyFq). And there is no change in Skener.xaml.cs .

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `DataType` to your XAML so it knows what type to validate the binding properties against

since you are using the code behind instead of a VM, specify the page class as the `DataType`

```
<ContentPage ...
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PapucoMetar.Views"
 ...
 x:DataType="local:Skener"
```